# start a bounty --> learn more... gives a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, help-center

Copied here from [start a bounty --> learn more... gives a 404](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6187/25907)

---

For any question, if you start a bounty, the first pop-up link has a learn more... link

The link points to https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounties which gives a 404.

Comment: The correct link is http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty (*singular*).

Comment: Thanks for the report. Just FYI: there's no need to copy bug reports from per-site metas to MSE. We monitor all sites.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be fixed on all sites as of 2014-10-06.